# MOXy Set/Map Mapping

Tags: java, eclipselink, moxy

I'm trying to use MOXy to generate a specifically formatted response for a front end client to make it easier for them to determine specific relationships. This is a bit of a contrived example, but I'm trying to do something like the following…

```java
public class Person {
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Address address;
}

public class Address {
    private String street;

    private String locality;

    private String state;

    private String zip;
}

public class PersonCollectionResponse {
    private Set<Person> people;

    public Set<Person> getPeople() {
        return this.people;
    }

    private int getCount() {
        return this.people.size();
    }
}
```

…and would like to end up with a result like…

```js
{
    "meta": {
        "count": 2
    },

    "people": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Danny Parker",
        "contact": {
            "locality": "Zoo York",
            "state": "New York"
        },
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Oscar the Grouch",
        "contact": {
            "locality": "San Francisco",
            "state": "California"
        }

    }],

    "mappings": [{
        "person": 1,
        "zip": 10014
    }, {
        "person": 2,
        "zip": 94102
    }]
}
```

Now the "people" set isn't very hard, but I'm stuck on how to get the mappings to work when writing the EclipseLink OXM metadata. I'm looking for a way to redefine how people get listed so that I can get my mapping.

```xml
<xml-element java-attribute="people">
    <xml-element java-attribute="id" xml-path="@id" />
    <xml-element java-attribute="zip" xml-path="@zip" />
</xml-element>
```

Not I get that might now be possible. So I created a getMappings on the PersonCollectionResponse that returns a List> that it generates from the people. Now this isn't ideal, but there are worse things. But when it is written out, the map objects are strings like so…

```js
"mappings": ["{person: 1, zip: 10014}", "{person: 2, zip: 94102}"]
```

So I guess my questions are one of these…

1. How can I display an element a second time but with a different output?
2. How can I output maps without them being quoted as strings?

Worst case scenario I guess is I make my set of generic maps into a new class objects and provide a schema for them too, but that is something I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently MOXy does not allow you to split the representation of a single instance into multiple locations within a JSON (or XML) tree.  Please enter an enhancement request for the type of support you would like to see:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink

Below I'll demonstrate how to map portions of your JSON message.

**PARTIAL ANSWER #1**

Below I'll describe how to map your model to the following JSON message:

```
{
   "meta" : {
      "count" : 2
   },
   "people" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Danny Parker",
      "contact" : {
         "locality" : "Zoo York",
         "state" : "New York"
      }
   }, {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Oscar the Grouch",
      "contact" : {
         "locality" : "San Francisco",
         "state" : "California"
      }
   } ]
}
```

***oxm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum11870107">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="PersonCollectionResponse">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="count" xml-path="meta/count/text()"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Person">
            <xml-type prop-order="id name address"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="address" name="contact"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Address">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="zip"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

---

**PARTIAL ANSWER #2**

Now I'll describe how to map your model to the following JSON message:

```
{
   "meta" : {
      "count" : 2
   },
   "mappings" : [ {
      "person" : 2,
      "zip" : "94102"
   }, {
      "person" : 1,
      "zip" : "10014"
   } ]
}
```

***oxm.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum11870107">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="PersonCollectionResponse">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="count" xml-path="meta/count/text()"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="people" name="mappings"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Person">
            <xml-type prop-order="id address"/>
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="id" name="person"/>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="name"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="address" xml-path="."/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="Address" xml-accessor-type="NONE">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="zip"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

The same demo code can be used with both partial solutions:

```
package forum11870107;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(1);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum11870107/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {PersonCollectionResponse.class}, properties);

        PersonCollectionResponse pcr = new PersonCollectionResponse();

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.setId(1);
        person1.setName("Danny Parker");
        pcr.getPeople().add(person1);
        Address address1 = new Address();
        address1.setLocality("Zoo York");
        address1.setState("New York");
        address1.setZip("10014");
        person1.setAddress(address1);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.setId(2);
        person2.setName("Oscar the Grouch");
        pcr.getPeople().add(person2);
        Address address2 = new Address();
        address2.setLocality("San Francisco");
        address2.setState("California");
        address2.setZip("94102");
        person2.setAddress(address2);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(pcr, System.out);
    }

}
```

---

**DOMAIN MODEL**

Below is the domain model that was used for both partial solutions:

***PersonCollectionResponse***

```
package forum11870107;

import java.util.*;

public class PersonCollectionResponse {
    private Set<Person> people = new HashSet<Person>();

    public Set<Person> getPeople() {
        return this.people;
    }

    public void setPeople(Set<Person> people) {
        this.people = people;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.people.size();
    }

}
```

***Person***

```
package forum11870107;

public class Person {
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private Address address;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

***Address***

```
package forum11870107;

public class Address {

    private String street;
    private String locality;
    private String state;
    private String zip;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getLocality() {
        return locality;
    }

    public void setLocality(String locality) {
        this.locality = locality;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getZip() {
        return zip;
    }

    public void setZip(String zip) {
        this.zip = zip;
    }

}
```

***jaxb.properties***

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html.

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: I don't have the reputation to vote yet so I can't up vote it, but thank you for your help. I guess if I want to do the mapping I want, I'll have to make a list of "PersonToZip" mapping objects or something. I'll definitely add that as a feature request though.

Comment: @Danny.Parker2002 - If you are interested in this feature I would recommend you submitting a feature request into our bug database (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=EclipseLink).  Externally entered bugs are generally given higher priority.  Also since you are new to Stack Overflow you can click the check mark icon next to my answer if you feel it has answer your question to accept it.  This gives us both some reputation points and indicates to others that you have got the answer you are looking for.